# Is there a correlation between government responsiveness to individual/voter concerns and subsequent reduction in policy demands?

Tags: united-states, election, russian-federation, china, economy

In democratic states, is there a correlation between government responsiveness to individual concerns and subsequent reduction in policy demands?

I am curious because recent polsci papers on autocratic states like China and Russia, there is empirical [evidence](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/ajps.12207) suggesting that not only are governments more responsive to citizens' demands online if they contain a threat for collective action but also that such responsiveness improves how individuals view their government (i.e. the online sentiment becomes more positive about the government).

I wonder if the empirical results from a country like China would hold in any democratic setting where individuals face less/no constraints to express themselves and their policy preferences. Theoretically, I would expect that in a democratic context like U.S, citizens might become even more engaged and increase their economic/education policy demands to local politicians if they feel that their voices are heard, rather than reduce them which is the finding in some [autocratic](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0010414014555443) countries.

A recent policy example that I can think of is the minimum wage policy increase in blue states, the responsiveness of local policymakers to voters' demands in raising the minimum wage appears to have motivated voters to advocate for greater labor policy demands (e.g. mandating longer maternity leave in private firms, etc..)

Comment: While this post uses different examples, it is not quite clear to me how this question differs from your previous *unanswered* question: [Is there a correlation between Gov't economic policies/performance & collective action](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/81070/26455).

Comment: Well neither the first one nor the second were answered clearly, so perhaps you can help by attempting to answer either or both?